# Laravel: How to build realtime chat for web, android and ios?

Tags: android, ios, laravel, sockets, chat

## Overview

I have to make a realtime  chat app for web-site and make opportunity to use chat server on Android and IOS apps.  (*For backend I use* **PHP framework Laravel**)

At first I thought to make it using Pusher, but customer wants chat app **without payment** for connections or messages. Unfortunately, Pusher is not free, so I thought to make own chat server using Socket.IO.

## Problem

Andoid and IOS developer (my team) told me that thay don't know how to build chat apps using Socket.IO server. They have no idea how to make realtime chat.
And I don't know what to offer them.
Other idea was to use Firebase realtime database (it's cheaper than Pusher)

## Questions

- Does anyone know **free** solutions to build realtime chat for Web, Android and IOS apps?
- Is it better to build own socket server or use something like Firebase?
- Is there are any tutorials or arcticles about that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be an acceptable answer in your case, but I'll still put it out here:

If your client is not willing to pay a small amount for good features, then they will have to be okay without those features.

It will take more development time and energy to research and implement another system for event broadcasting.

If your time is chargeable, they will most likely be paying much more for your services implementing some other unknown plugin than they would pay to use Pusher or other Laravel supported package.

The Laravel ecosystem has closen those packages because they are robust and clean to use by developers.

Even if you don't choose this answer, I hope people reading this will consider the implications of settling for less on such a big necessity (in cases such as the OP's).

Comment: The app I'm building shold have 10000+ chat connections. Pusher wants 500$/month for this. My customer don't want to pay so much. And I can't explain him that it's necessary. Unfortunately

Comment: Have you looked into Redis?

Comment: What do you meen? How can I use Redis as chat server for different devices?

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/step-by-step-guide-to-installing-socketio-and-broadcasting-events-with-laravel-51

You use it as a broadcaster for incoming notifications and data. Then you use ajax calls back as responses.

Comment: I have already wrote that I thought to make own chat server using Socket.IO but IOS and Android devs told that they don't know how to use websockets in mobile apps

Comment: So your issue is not in what broadcaster to use then.. It is that you are working with developers that can't help you.

Comment: Maybe it is ... I have never build something like chat which can be used for mobile apps, so I asked my team about that. But they also don't know. So after hours of googling I decided to ask there about best solution

Comment: I have never built something to handle that many connections at once, but the idea of chat is fairly simple. 

When someone sends a text, use an ajax call to update the DB table with their text message, where it is going to, etc. That should trigger an event also, which uses broadcasting to send information to a client such as Socket.io. This allows the frontend to be updated in real time to whoever is on that specific channel. And then the process is repeated again. 

So I'm not exactly sure how to do it in Android or iOS, but I'm sure there's a way to register them to a broadcasting channel.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check XMPP for implementing chat application in iOS,

Please refer, [XMPP](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/blog/build-a-complete-ios-messaging-app-using-xmppframework-tutorial-part-1.html)

Comment: To use XMPP I need to create Jabber account for each user of my application?

Comment: Yes, Every individual on the XMPP network is identified by a Jabber ID.

Comment: I just tried to use XMPP web-chat build using Converse.js https://inverse.chat/ It's a bad realization of realtime chat. Just ajax requests, no websockets